# Geometry: Undefined concepts put into a context

Tags: integration

Reading Hilbert's axioms for Euclidean geometry, the notions of points and lines are left undefined, that is, they are the building blocks we start from. However, when looking at a specific model for Euclidean geometry, such as R^2, "points" are now tuples of real numbers (x,y). My question is: When looking at a concrete model, are the notions of points and lines still considered primitive and undefined? Since in R^2, when asked "What is a point?", one would answer: "A tuple (x,y) of reals!" Thanks in advance!